# Pop-ups do not work with mobile web view

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, top-bar

The "Recent inbox messages" and "Recent achievements" pop-ups do no work
anymore with the mobile web view:

[image]

The background is changed to gray when I click on the icon, but
no pop-up appears.

The pop-up on the left (with the list of your communities and all other  Stack Exchange sites) doesn't work either, it jumps directly to http://stackexchange.com.

- Tested with:

  - Safari on macOS and Mobile Safari on iOS.
  - Chrome latest on Windows 7
- Observed on all sites (e.g. Stack Overflow, Mathematics Stack Exchange, 
  Meta Stack Exchange, and more).

Comment: @Pat whoa, they are quick!

Comment: It works in "Full Site" mode, but not mobile web mode. On Samsung Browser (chromium), S4.

Comment: OK, developer is now aware of this, so expect a fix shortly.

Comment: @cde true, the mobile web view is using different JS, and the bug is there somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about this, my fault. I added code earlier that performs some measurements in order to support both the old and the new top nav, and that code made an assumption that isn't correct in the mobile view (namely that the top bar has a positioned ancestor, in case you were curious).

Fix for this is being deployed right now.

Since there's speculation in the comments under your question: This isn't about testing the new header on all network sites. Both header versions just use the same code (as much as possible), so you'll see references to the new header in the JavaScript on other sites as well.

Comment: Fix confirmed. [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, it was done deploying about twenty seconds before you posted that comment :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing it so quickly!